# Class Interface which can create N number of methods

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I am working on creation of dynamic form in C++ which needs to make user entry N entries. The number N is based upon the application type decided by the user - assuming that all fields are of same type. The client will inherit that interface.

Hence I am trying to create an Interface (using templates or any other methods) but un-able to create such an interface.

Is the same possible - if yes please provide an example?

Example pseudo-code for a form of 10 fields:

```
template<int i>
class Field {
public:
    Field () {  
    for (int index = 0 ; index < i ; index ++)

    }
};

template<>
class Field<1> {
public:
Field(char * name , int value);
};

class Form : public Field<10>
{
 virtual Field1 (char * name , int value) =0;
 ..........................................
 virtual Field10 (char * name , int value) =0;
 // so based upon the value of N provided this class should have N pure virtual methods
}
```

Comment: sounds like you need a `std::vector` of `entries`.

Comment: sorry but isn't clear, to me, what do you want; can you write a pseudo-code example?

Comment: Added pseudo-code example for clarification

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fErrk7zQ I don't know how to make it generate functions for you and have your sub-class automatically implement it.. That might be impossible afaik :S

Comment: How about `virtual Field(int field_index, char * name , int value) =0;`?

Comment: I believe that it will create only one interface method - so how can we force the user entry that many entries?

Comment: Check the amount of entries created...

Comment: Then the issue I feel is there are no methods to input N entries?

Comment: There is nothing preventing inputting of N entries...

Comment: But its an interface for which will create an implementation class - hence when object of class is created the user needs to override the methods which is the actual logic to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to do that.

You said you want all fields of the same type.

Here is a simple solution with a vector.

If you like you can also easily change my example to use a map if you want to access fields by name rather than by index.

```
/*********************
 *  File: main.cpp   *
 *********************/

#include <iostream>
#include "Form.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Form<int> form(15);

    // The first field is the customer number
    form.setFieldName(0, "customer number");
    form.setFieldValue(0, 4711);

    // The second field is the order number
    form.setFieldName(1, "order number");
    form.setFieldValue(1, 1234);

    // The third field is an article number
    form.setFieldName(2, "article number");
    form.setFieldValue(2, 6789);

    // ... and so on ...
    // Read some values back

    cout << "This is the second field:" << endl;
    cout << "Field Name:  [" << form.getFieldName(1) << "]" << endl;
    cout << "Field Value: [" << form.getFieldValue(1) << "]" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the template included in Main.cpp:

```
/*****************
 * File: Form.h  *
 *****************/

#pragma once
#include "FormField.h"

template<class T>
class Form
{
public:
    explicit Form(const int size);
    virtual ~Form() = default;
    void setFieldName(int index, const std::string& name);
    const std::string& getFieldName(int index) const;
    void setFieldValue(int index, const T& value);
    const T& getFieldValue(int index) const;
private:
    std::vector<FormField<T>> formFields;
};

template<class T>
Form<T>::Form(const int size)
    : formFields(size)
{ }

template<class T>
void Form<T>::setFieldName(int index, const std::string& name)
{
    formFields[index].setName(name);
}

template<class T>
const std::string& Form<T>::getFieldName(int index) const
{
    return formFields[index].getName();
}

template<class T>
void Form<T>::setFieldValue(int index, const T& value)
{
    formFields[index].setValue(value);
}

template<class T>
const T& Form<T>::getFieldValue(int index) const
{
    return formFields[index].getValue();
}
```

And this is the template for the FormField:

```
/**********************
 * File: FormField.h  *
 **********************/

#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
class FormField
{
public:
    explicit FormField();
    virtual ~FormField() = default;
    const std::string& getName() const;
    void setName(const std::string& name);
    const T& getValue() const;
    void setValue(const T& value);
private:
    std::string name;
    T value;
};

template<class T>
FormField<T>::FormField()
    : name(), value()
{
}

template<class T>
const std::string& FormField<T>::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

template<class T>
const T& FormField<T>::getValue() const
{
    return value;
}

template<class T>
void FormField<T>::setName(const std::string& name)
{
    this->name = name;
}

template<class T>
void FormField<T>::setValue(const T& value)
{
    this->value = value;
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks - it suffice the needs but is there a way that we can force the code to give compilation error until all fields are set?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand what do you exactly want but... I suppose you can use recursion and a tag type (say `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>`, where `N` is the template argument of `Field`) to differentiate getter and setter at different levels.

I mean... given the following `Field`

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Field : public Field<T, N-1u>
 {
   private:
      std::string  name;
      T            value;

   public:
      using Field<T, N-1u>::setField;
      using Field<T, N-1u>::getFieldName;
      using Field<T, N-1u>::getFieldValue;

      using icnc = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> const;

      virtual void setField (icnc &, std::string const & n0, T const & v0)
       {
         name  = n0;
         value = v0;
       }

      virtual std::string const & getFieldName (icnc &) const
       { return name; }

      virtual T const & getFieldValue (icnc &) const
       { return value; }
 };
```

and a ground specialization `Field<0>` that define fake methods

```
template <typename T>
class Field<T, 0u>
 {
   public:
      // fake ground functions
      virtual void setField      () { };
      virtual void getFieldName  () { };
      virtual void getFieldValue () { };
 };
```

defining `Form` as follows

```
class Form : public Field<int, 10u>
 { };
```

you have 10 virtual setters and 20 (10 for names and 10 for values) virtual getters.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Field : public Field<T, N-1u>
 {
   private:
      std::string  name;
      T            value;

   public:
      using Field<T, N-1u>::setField;
      using Field<T, N-1u>::getFieldName;
      using Field<T, N-1u>::getFieldValue;

      using icnc = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> const;

      virtual void setField (icnc &, std::string const & n0, T const & v0)
       {
         name  = n0;
         value = v0;
       }

      virtual std::string const & getFieldName (icnc &) const
       { return name; }

      virtual T const & getFieldValue (icnc &) const
       { return value; }
 };

template <typename T>
class Field<T, 0u>
 {
   public:
      // fake ground functions
      virtual void setField      () { };
      virtual void getFieldName  () { };
      virtual void getFieldValue () { };
 };

class Form : public Field<int, 3u>
 {
   // Form inherit three different setField, three different getFieldName
   // and three different getFieldValie methods
 };

template <std::size_t N>
using tag = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> const;


int main ()
 {
   Form  f;

   f.setField(tag<1u>{}, "field 1", 111);
   f.setField(tag<2u>{}, "field 2", 222);
   f.setField(tag<3u>{}, "field 3", 333);

   std::cout << f.getFieldName(tag<1u>{}) << ", "
      << f.getFieldValue(tag<1u>{}) << std::endl;
   std::cout << f.getFieldName(tag<2u>{}) << ", "
      << f.getFieldValue(tag<2u>{}) << std::endl;
   std::cout << f.getFieldName(tag<3u>{}) << ", "
      << f.getFieldValue(tag<3u>{}) << std::endl;
 }
```

Working a little more inside `Form`, adding a template setter and a couple of template getters

```
class Form : public Field<int, 3u>
 {
   public:
      using Field<int, 3u>::setField;
      using Field<int, 3u>::getFieldName;
      using Field<int, 3u>::getFieldValue;

      template <std::size_t N>
      using tag = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> const;

      template <std::size_t N>
      void setField (std::string const & n0, int v0)
       { setField(tag<N>{}, n0, v0); }

      template <std::size_t N>
      std::string const & getFieldName () const
       { return getFieldName(tag<N>{}); }

      template <std::size_t N>
      int const & getFieldValue () const
       { return getFieldValue(tag<N>{}); }
 };
```

you can make simpler the use of the tag index

```
   Form  f;

   f.setField<1u>("field 1", 111);
   f.setField<2u>("field 2", 222);
   f.setField<3u>("field 3", 333);

   std::cout << f.getFieldName<1u>() << ", " << f.getFieldValue<1u>()
      << std::endl;
   std::cout << f.getFieldName<2u>() << ", " << f.getFieldValue<2u>()
      << std::endl;
   std::cout << f.getFieldName<3u>() << ", " << f.getFieldValue<3u>()
      << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - it suffice the needs but is there a way that we can force the code to give compilation error until all fields are set?

Comment: I suppose an error in a get-field template method (see last part of my answer); by example you can add a boolean flag in every `Field` specialization and a method tho check the flag in the following `Field` (and, recursively, every flag).